# Why doesn't this PHP MySQL registration form work?

Tags: php, mysql

So I wrote a very basic PHP registration form linking in with a HTML file; here's the code in PHP:

```
 <?php
if( $_POST )
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","KyleHulse","(my password)", "csdb1082");

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("csdb1082", $Users);


$insert_query = "insert into feedback(
                user,
                password,
                email
                    ) 
                    values (
            '".$_POST['user']."',
            '".$_POST['password']."',
            '".$_POST['email']."')";

mysql_query($insert_query);

echo "<h2>Thanks for registering.</h2>";

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

And here's the corresponding HTML code:

```
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

The annoying thing is I had it working earlier, something I changed caused it to break.

Comment: What errors are you getting?? and the `mysql` extension is depreciated, you should be using `MySQLi` or other procedure like extensions.

Comment: When did it work? And what did you change when it stopped working?

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions!!!! Use the corresponding `mysqli_` functions instead... This is important!!! Note the difference in the names mysql<->mysql**i**

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider using Prepared Statements or PDO instead.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: So much wrong with this code (depricated functions, SQL injections, Plain passwords). Maybe you should try another tutorial?

Comment: Precisely, I use my own small personal projects to enjoy coding with features that I'm not allowed in commercial projects that always have restrictions like "needs to run in our 10yo server" and painful work like reimplementing native libraries in userland code. Whatever...

Comment: @Kyle Hulse Can you add these lines at the start of php code ->
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); To check if there is an error on page..

Comment: I would like to mention here that no matter if you work for your personal project or a commercial, it is always a good idea to follow industry standards. What you do is actually what you practice. So always practice good. I have posted a detailed answer with Prepared Statement that is working. Feel free to copy/paste as I have used your values in the answer.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the modified code with Prepared Statement.

First step is to connect to the database. To do that, we need to define the access details.

```
// Define Database Credentials
$servername = "localhost"; //Server Name
$username = "KyleHulse"; //Username to the DB
$password = "(my password)"; //Password to the DB
$dbname = "csdb1082"; //Name of the Database

// Create Database Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Now check the connection.

```
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

After this, you run your query. Please note that since this is your personal project, therefore I am using `SHA1` as the hashing of your password. For a bigger project, I recommend to research further on how to secure your password.

To run the query, first is to prepare it. This is how you do.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO feedback (user, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
```

In this, you store the statement in `$stmt` variable. The query has `INSERT INTO` followed by the table's name. In your case it is `feedback`.

After this, you fill in the table's fields to be saved in first bracket. In your case it will be `(user, password, email)` followed by `VALUES`.

After this you add placeholders for the actual values using `(?, ?, ?)`. Please note that the total count of `?` must match the total count of fields in the previous bracket.

Now you have to bind the variables to these `?`. This is done by,

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $user, $password, $email);
```

Please note that `"sss"` are the formats of values passed. Below are the formats.

```
i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB
```

So you need to pass 3 values, therefore you have 3 `s`, followed by the variables where you will store the values from HTML form by,

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
$password = sha1($_POST["password"]); //simplest way to use SHA1 hash.
$email = $_POST["email"];
```

Now you just need to execute the prepared statement.

```
$stmt->execute();
```

That's it!

Below is the full code.

```
// Define Database Credentials
$servername = "localhost"; //Server Name
$username = "KyleHulse"; //Username to the DB
$password = "(my password)"; //Password to the DB
$dbname = "csdb1082"; //Name of the Database

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO feedback (user, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $user, $password, $email);

$user = $_POST["user"];
$password = sha1($_POST["password"]); //simplest way to use SHA1 hash.
$email = $_POST["email"];

$stmt->execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_slect_db()` - use `$con` not `$Users` ($Users not defined even);

And use `mysqli`, not deprecated and unsafe `mysql` functions :)

Comment: Code still fails to function

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's your personal project but it will be good if you do things in a right way. There is much to improve in code but lets jump to what you really need, Also make sure php error reporting is on in php.ini in development phase.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","KyleHulse","(your password)", "csdb1082");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback(user,password,email) VALUES(
            '".$_POST['user']."',
            '".$_POST['password']."',
            '".$_POST['email']."'
        )";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "<h2>Thanks for registering.</h2>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```