# login page getting post back to same page

Tags: php, html, authentication

i am trying to log in to a form by passing the correct credentials but its posting back to the same page again as i click login. i replaced session_register("adminusername"), since my php server got upgraded and as it was not working. the real problem started only after php server upgrade.

```
       <? session_start();
       ?>
       <?php
        include('../dbconnect.php');

        $myusername=$_POST['txtusername']; 
        $mypassword=$_POST['txtpassword']; 


        $sql="SELECT * FROM adminlogin WHERE adminusername='$myusername' and 
        adminpassword='$mypassword'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=@mysql_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 
        1 row

        if($count==1){
        //session_register("adminusername");
        $_SESSION['adminusername']= $myusername;
        //session_register("mypassword"); 
        $_SESSION['mypassword']= "mypassword";
        header("location:index.php");
        }
        else {

        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        ob_start();
        ?>

        <?PHP
        header('location:login.php?Action=wrong');
        exit();


        } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Maybe because you are using an old deprecated and security porous API `mysql`.. This code shouldn't be live in production.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to use `mysqli` with Prepared Statements or PDO. This is not only because `mysql` is deprecated, but it protects to from SQL Injection as well.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183181/why-doesnt-this-php-mysql-registration-form-work/47183880#47183880) to have a ready-to-use registration code with Prepared Statements. You can replace your details in it.

Comment: its a login page to log into admin control panel !!